# Simple clickable link in Cocoa and Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, hyperlink

Im writing a desktop app in swift for mac 10.11 and I would like to add a link to the about page.

Very much like this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1487/_index.html

I haven't been able to find a good tutorial or reference.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 7):

Swift 4, xCode 9

```
@IBDesignable
class HyperlinkTextField: NSTextField {

    @IBInspectable var href: String = ""

    override func resetCursorRects() {
        discardCursorRects()
        addCursorRect(self.bounds, cursor: NSCursor.pointingHand)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // TODO:  Fix this and get the hover click to work.

        let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
            NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: NSColor.linkColor,
            NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue as AnyObject
        ]
        attributedStringValue = NSAttributedString(string: self.stringValue, attributes: attributes)
    }

    override func mouseDown(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
        if let localHref = URL(string: href) {
            NSWorkspace.shared.open(localHref)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: changed NSColor.blue to NSColor.linkColor for better support in 10.14

Comment: If ```NSAttributedStringKey``` doesn't show up in the suggestions use ```NSAttributedString.Key``` and for ```NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor``` use ```NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor```

Answer (score 5):

Modified the existing answers to allow for a substring of the label's text to become underlined and blue, so you can do something like: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340282/simple-clickable-link-in-cocoa-and-swift) is the answer

```
// A text field that can contain a hyperlink within a range of characters in the text.
@IBDesignable
public class SubstringLinkedTextField: NSTextField {
    // the URL that will be opened when the link is clicked.
    public var link: String = ""
    @available(*, unavailable, message: "This property is reserved for Interface Builder. Use 'link' instead.")
    @IBInspectable public var HREF: String {
        get {
            return self.link
        }
        set {
            self.link = newValue
            self.needsDisplay = true
        }
    }

    // the substring within the field's text that will become an underlined link. if empty or no match found, the entire text will become the link.
    public var linkText: String = ""
    @available(*, unavailable, message: "This property is reserved for Interface Builder. Use 'linkText' instead.")
    @IBInspectable public var LinkText: String {
        get {
            return self.linkText
        }
        set {
            self.linkText = newValue
            self.needsDisplay = true
        }
    }

    override public func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
        self.isSelectable = true

        let url = URL(string: self.link)
        let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: AnyObject] = [
            NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.link.rawValue): url as AnyObject
        ]
        let attributedStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.stringValue)

        if self.linkText.count > 0 {
            if let range = self.stringValue.indexOf(substring: self.linkText) {
                attributedStr.setAttributes(attributes, range: range)
            } else {
                attributedStr.setAttributes(attributes, range: NSMakeRange(0, self.stringValue.count))
            }
        } else {
            attributedStr.setAttributes(attributes, range: NSMakeRange(0, self.stringValue.count))
        }
        self.attributedStringValue = attributedStr
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to subclass `NSTextField` to create a `HyperlinkTextField`. Below is an example:

First, let's add a `HyperlinkTextField` class to your project:

```
// HyperlinkTextField.swift

import Cocoa

@IBDesignable
class HyperlinkTextField: NSTextField {
    @IBInspectable var href: String = ""

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        let attributes: [String: AnyObject] = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: NSColor.blueColor(),
            NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue
        ]
        self.attributedStringValue = NSAttributedString(string: self.stringValue, attributes: attributes)
    }

    override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openURL(NSURL(string: self.href)!)
    }
}
```

Next, in Interface Builder, drag a label from the Object library to your window.

Select that label, go to the menu *View > Utilities > Show Identity Inspector* (or press `Cmd + Opt + 3`) and change the class to `HyperlinkTextField`

[image: Identity Inspector]

Go to the *Attributes Inspector* (`Cmd + Opt + 4`) and set `Href` to the URL you want to visit.

[image: Attributes Inspector]

The label shows black text in Interface Builder but everything will be fine when you run your app. Clicking on the label will open the link in your default browser.

One thing I couldn't achieve was to make the `HyperlinkTextField` shows up as blue and underlined in Interface Builder. Comments on how to do that are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly what I needed. Here is the `Swift3` version:

```
import Cocoa

@IBDesignable
class HyperTextField: NSTextField {
    @IBInspectable var href: String = ""

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        let attributes: [String: AnyObject] = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: NSColor.blue,
            NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue as AnyObject
        ]
        self.attributedStringValue = NSAttributedString(string: self.stringValue, attributes: attributes)
    }

    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        NSWorkspace.shared().open(URL(string: self.href)!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let link = NSTextField()
link.isBezeled = false
link.drawsBackground = false
link.isEditable = false
link.isSelectable = true
link.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com")
let linkTextAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue,
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: NSColor.blue,
        NSAttributedStringKey.link: url as Any
            ]
let string = "whatever"
link.attributedStringValue = NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: linkTextAttributes)
window.contentView?.addSubview(link)
```

Answer (score 0):

swift 4.2

```
class HyperlinkTextField: NSTextField {


private var detector: NSDataDetector!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
     detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
}


func setText(text: String ){
    let matches = detector.matches(in: text, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.utf16.count))

    for match in matches {
        guard let range = Range(match.range, in: text) else { continue }
        let url = text[range]
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: url, range: match.range)
        self.attributedStringValue = attributedString
    }
}
```

}