# How to make the text as a hyperlink in NSTextView programmatically? Swift 4, Xcode 9.4

Tags: swift, macos, nstextview

How to make the text as a hyperlink in NSTextView programmatically?

Like this:

> Just [click here](http://example.com) to register

or like this:

> Just http://example.com to register

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238366/uitextview-with-hyperlink-text/39238647#39238647) but it works only for iOS, not for macOS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple clickable link in Cocoa and Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340282/simple-clickable-link-in-cocoa-and-swift)

Comment: @Carpsen90 it is about NSTextField and it uses a storyboard, so it is not a programmatic way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Just click here to register")
let range = NSRange(location: 5, length: 10)
let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!

attributedString.setAttributes([.link: url], range: range)
textView.textStorage?.setAttributedString(attributedString)

// Define how links should look like within the text view
textView.linkTextAttributes = [
    .foregroundColor: NSColor.blue,
    .underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue
]
```

Comment: It works, thank you! Don't you also know how can I change the cursor to pointer when I hover the link? :)

Comment: The question was for MacOS not for iOS

Comment: Hi, on Swift 5 developing a macOS app, this does not produce a clickable link. Anything I'm missing to get it working? The text is blue an underlined properly but it's not clickable for some reason.

Comment: @user3064009 Check that your NSTextView is "Selectable" in Interface Builder.  It's a checkbox and without it the NSTextView ignores mouse clicks, thus preventing your link from being clickable.

Answer (score 1):

If you needed set Font Size for links use this ->

```
    let input = "Your string with urls"
      
      let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
      let matches = detector.matches(in: input, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: input.utf16.count))
      
      let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)]
      let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: input, attributes: attributes)
      if matches.count > 0{
           for match in matches {
                guard let range = Range(match.range, in: input) else { continue }
                let url = input[range]
                
                attributedString.setAttributes([.link: url, .font: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)], range: match.range)
           
           
           }
      }
      
      youTextView.textStorage?.setAttributedString(attributedString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 / macOS 12 solution to make the link clickable and have the same font any NSTextField's you display in the same window:

Define some NSTextView IBOutlet (mine is called `tutorialLink`):

```
@IBOutlet weak var tutorialLink : NSTextView!
```

Then here's the styling code in one function:

```
fileprivate func initTutorialLink() {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Here's a tutorial on how to set up a Digital Ocean S3 account.")
    
    // Set font for entire string
    let fontAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)]
    let range2 = NSRange(location: 0, length: 61)
    attributedString.setAttributes(fontAttributes, range: range2)
    
    // Set url and same font for just the link range
    let range = NSRange(location: 21, length: 40)
    let url = URL(string: tutorialUrl)!
    attributedString.setAttributes([.link: url, NSAttributedString.Key.font:NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)], range: range)
    
    // Store the attributed string
    tutorialLink.textStorage?.setAttributedString(attributedString)
    
    // Mark how link text should be colored and underlined
    tutorialLink.linkTextAttributes = [
        .foregroundColor: NSColor.systemBlue,
        .underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue
    ]
    
    // Give non-linked text same color as other labels
    tutorialLink.textColor = .labelColor
}
```

In IB, you obviously need to connect your NSTextView (called Scrollable Text View in the Objects Library) to the IBOutlet.  **Less obviously, you need to click the box to make the NSTextView `Selectable`.**  I don't know why exactly, but if it's not `Selectable` then your link will not react when clicked.

Comment: > Non-selectable text views do not process any mouse events

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextview/1449297-selectable