# Is there a way to contain a url within a controller in macOS swift 5

Tags: swift, macos, url, nsviewcontroller

Thanks to this [q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340282/simple-clickable-link-in-cocoa-and-swift), I've added a URL to an NSTextField. Is it possible to contain the web page in my own view controller?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by containing but you can use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview for displaying web content on you application

Comment: Yes. I had the notion that WKWebView was only for iOS. By contain, I was thinking of setting the web view in a frame. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the WebKit framework and use a WKWebView instance for showing web pages.

Documentation for WKWebView: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview

WKWebView allows to load a url as a usual web browser and it also can read HTML/CSS code that stored as a string. So much powerful tool.

My open source project that highlights swift code for web sites uses WKWebView for previewing generated HTML/CSS output, here is the ViewController:

https://github.com/uberdeviant/Swiftlighter/blob/master/Swiftlighter/Contollers/WebPreviewViewController.swift